# Update jsonb with the new keys but preserve the value if the existing obj has the key

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I need to update the existing object. The resulting object will own all and only the keys from the new one, but if the same key already exist, I need to copy the value.
Something like a merge, but only for values if they have the same key.

**Example**:
Existing in db: `{"a":1,"b":2, "c":3}`,
New object: `{"a":999, "d": 4}`
Result: `{"a":1, "d":4}` - "a" get the value from existing data, "b" is gone, "d" is added.

This is for my special 'upsert' query. What I've done so far is the simple:

```
INSERT ....
ON CONFLICT (project_id, other_stuf)
    DO UPDATE SET payload = excluded.payload || answers.payload
```

but it's not deleting the "b" in the above example.

Thoughts?

Comment: Asking people to follow the guidelines by asking a specific question, rather than a vague *Thoughs?* or *Any ideas?* isn't being mean. You may want to review the [help] pages, especially [ask]. It's also not *useless* to try to educate relatively new users on the proper way to use this site. You can do better than a personal attack, I'm sure - use the effort to [edit] your post and ask properly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `jsonb_each` with `jsonb_object_agg`:

```
SET payload = (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(
    key,
    (CASE WHEN answers.payload ? key THEN answers.payload->key ELSE value)
  )
  FROM jsonb_each(excluded.payload)
)
```

or shortened to

```
SET payload = (
  SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, COALESCE(answers.payload->key, value))
  FROM jsonb_each(excluded.payload)
)
```

Comment: works like charm. I used the 2nd version as it is most elegant and easy to understand.
Thanks!